# How do I get random from the three latest rows?

Tags: php

I wonder how I can pick one out of the latest three rows from a table.
I have this:

```
"SELECT * FROM blog_content ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3"
```

I thought: save the result in an array and random 0-2 and pick from the array, but that wouldn't work since there's many rows.

Comment: Try using `ORDER BY rand()`

Comment: That doesn't work, since I need the latest three rows and then random one out of those.

Comment: You may want to read this: http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/avoid-rand-in-mysql

Comment: @William N Oh, I see. Sorry about that.

Comment: @James Black This article basically says there's a performance hit proportional to the number of rows because each row gets assigned a random number. In this particular case, the OP wants to pull 3 rows and pick one of them at random.Not a big issue IMO.

Comment: @alexg - I thought about it after I considered the answer, but some others beat me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to pick one at random out of the latest 3. Try a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM blog_content ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3) t ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: "Every derived table must have its own alias"; I'm using mysql_query, can't do two queries I think?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM blog_content ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3) last_three
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM blog_content ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3) AS recentBlogs ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Worked for me.